# How to reset browser zoom in reactjs web app on ios safari?

Tags: reactjs, safari, pinchzoom

I cannot reset the browser zoom on route change in a reactjs web app in mobile safari browser. Tried the below approaches but no luck.

- Reload the page on router hash change.
- Viewport meta tag is no longer supported by ios.
- touch-action css is also not helping as it is partially supported in
  safari browser.

Comment: Any code or something?

Comment: @ Saeid. It's a react web app with hash routing. When you zoom on one page (e.g. home) and go to the other page (e.g. contacts) the zoom should get restored to normal. Currently the zoom does not restore to normal, it remains same as that of the previous page.